# Как правильно сделать запрос в mySQL?

Tags: mysql

Есть часть кода:

```
$k = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cars.*, SUM(cars_fuel.distance) as distance, SUM(cars_fuel.fuel) as fuel,
                    SUM(cars_fuel.money) as money
              FROM cars, cars_fuel 
              WHERE cars.car_user_id = :user_id AND (cars.car_id = cars_fuel.cars_fuel_cars_id OR cars.car_id NOT IN cars_fuel)  AND cars.delete_date IS NULL
              GROUP BY cars_fuel.cars_fuel_cars_id");
        $k->execute(['user_id'=>$lg]);
```

В таблице `cars` имеются записи об автомобилях `cars.car_id`.
А в таблице `cars_fuel` - данные по расходу топлива этих автомобилей.

Вопрос: Как написать запрос, чтобы в результате `$cars = $k->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` отображались все автомобили с таблицы `cars`, а не только те автомобили, у которых есть записи в `cars_fuel`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$k = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cars.*, SUM(cars_fuel.distance) as distance, SUM(cars_fuel.fuel) as fuel,
                    SUM(cars_fuel.money) as money
              FROM cars
              LEFT JOIN cars_fuel ON (cars.car_id = cars_fuel.cars_fuel_cars_id)
              WHERE cars.car_user_id = :user_id AND cars.delete_date IS NULL
              GROUP BY cars.car_id");
        $k->execute(['user_id'=>$lg]);

        $cars = $k->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```